# Когда аккаунт удаляется с сохранением голосов?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, удаление-профиля

Недавно был удалён [пользователь](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227049/FoggyFinder) - по собственному желанию.

Но меня интересует не этот момент. В справке [говорится](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed):

> Отмена голосов происходит при удалении любого пользователя, кроме тех, кто имеет крайне высокую репутацию. Поскольку такими пользователями обычно было отдано огромное количество голосов, их отмена может существенно отразиться на репутации других участников сообщества. В таких случаях используется специальное удаление, которое сохраняет голоса и не изменяет репутации тех, за или против кого голосовал удалённый пользователь.

Т. е. если репутация была достаточно высокой, то отката голосов происходить не должно. Но в данном случае эта схема использована не была. Лично у меня из-за этого удаления -185, а [в чате](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45057148#45057148) есть скриншот на -670:

> [image]

**Итак, каковы же критерии применения особого удаления с сохранением голосов?**

Comment: Я слышал как-то в чате, что если удалённый участник голосовал более полугода назад, то его голоса не откатываются, если менее - то откатываются.

Comment: так тут вопрос в том была ли репутация удаленного участника достаточно высокой?

Comment: @Grundy, ну судя по результату - не была. Вопрос - какая репутация является достаточно высокой.

Comment: Вообще не понятна связь рейтинга пользователя здесь, он может иметь низкий рейтинг, но быть старым участником и иметь много голосов

Comment: В английской справке это выглядит вот так: *"Because high-reputation users have usually cast a great many votes, removing all of them could be that much more disruptive to other users. In such cases, the staff use a special deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change for those who had been voted on by that user."* Звучит так, будто выбор, сохранять голоса или нет, производится вручную.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, обращаю внимание на _"the staff"_ - сотрудники.

Comment: А пользователей только сотрудники могут удалять, или бубновые модераторы тоже?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, модераторы - тоже. Но у модераторов точно нет выбора по сохранению голосов.

Comment: Только у сотрудников доступ к голосам есть )

Answer (score 6):

Я задал на MSE вопрос в свете недавнего удаления @Other: [How many reputation exactly should a deleted user have to prevent vote invalidation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315459/260198)

1. Репа в целом роли никакой не играет. Были случаи, когда топовый пользователь удалил аккаунт, все его голоса отменили: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10927/315118
2. Сослались на этот ответ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/260198

Если коротко, то критериев чётких нет, репутация, в целом не важна. Как решит левая пятка проверяющего, так и поступят.