# Когда пользователь удалён, пропадают ли его голоса?

Tags: поддержка, голосование, удаление-профиля

Ясно понятно, что пропадает репутация, а сами циферки около вопросов/ответов тоже меняются или нет?

Comment: Очень похожее обсуждение: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7429/213987 - как по мне так тянет на полный дубликат

Comment: Репутация тут почти напрямую зависит от количества голосов. Откат репутации - лишь следствие отката голосов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Когда аккаунт удаляется с сохранением голосов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7429/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в предложенном дубликате информация по голосам на сообщениях не раскрывается, как я вижу. Обсуждается только репутация, которую получили авторы сообщений на основании голосов от удалённого пользователя.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Провёл такой эксперимент: присоединился к сообществу [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), нашёл [старый ответ](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234) с нулевым рейтингом

> [image: Номинальное сообщение]

> [image: Номинальная шкала]

и проголосовал за него, убедился, что [автор](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/22/raleigh-buckner) получил репутационные +10,

> [image: Сообщение после голосования]

> [image: Шкала после голосования]

после чего удалил свой аккаунт. В итоге, репутация автора откатилась назад, однако единственный голос на ответе сохранился (может быть это, конечно, проявление кэша, так что стоит ещё попозже проверить его).

> [image: Сообщение после удаления аккаунта]

При этом во [временной шкале ответа](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/234/timeline) никаких упоминаний о голосах уже нет.

> [image: Шкала после удаления аккаунта]

---

Более поздняя проверка выявила факт сброса голосов на сообщениях.

**Таким образом, при удалении аккаунта отменяется как репутация, так и рейтинг. Последний при этом с заметной задержкой.**

---

При этом факт принятия ответа (зелёная галочка) сохраняется, если вдруг автор вопроса потом решит удалить свою учётную запись. Список таких принятых ответов может быть обнаружен в [профиле Духа Сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0?tab=activity&sort=accepts), к которому они в итоге переходят во владение.

Comment: спасибо, вот у меня вчера закрались подозрения, но я сам так сделать не додумался, подозрения закрались когда я наткнулся на какой то вопрос с удаленным автором и принятым ответом на котором стояла галка и 1плюс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я ещё на GameDev вам голос дал :) Но там (видимо из-за того, что я пару раз проголосовал вместо одного) удаление аккаунта система отложила на 24 часа. Можно будет посмотреть ещё раз, что случится с голосом на ответе (репутация же точно откатится).

Comment: при чтении комментов по ссылке на дубликат и английской меты по ссылкам у меня сложилось впечатление что там речь исключительно про репу, хотя иногда упоминалось слово голос, но все рано не ясно про что речь. и я вижу эту Вашу единицу спасибо.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ кстати, любопытно, смогу ли я снова проголосовать на том ответе после возвращения на сайт. Если да, то это дыра :)

Comment: @может еще такое быть что репу дадут а + не будет

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хех. Теперь уже не дают удалить профиль. Видимо, всё же источник голосов привязывается к аккаунту сетевому что ли.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вот и на GD голос остался, а в [шкале его нет](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/162528/timeline).

Comment: осталось попробовать проверить создать профиль еще раз и проголосовать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так я еще вчера проверил. На сообщении андроид энтузиастов. Даже коммент выше об этом был.

Comment: да, Вы там писали про 24 часа и я не так Вас понял

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вскрылись новые обстоятельства.

Comment: какие такие подробности?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ см. историю ответа. Голоса (рейтинг) откатились в итоге.